# Activity creashes when i use setSupportActionBar()

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I've already tried to set `AppTheme` **windowActionBar to false**, set the application's theme to my customized one and also the activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml file`, set the theme in the toolbar.xml but nothing works

Where's my actual code:

**Toolbar:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Styles.xml:**

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
<application>

        <activity android:name=".home.Home">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**Java class:**

```
Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_draw);
        setTitle("Coffee Hour");
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

**Layout xml:**

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />
```

Comment: check if you imported correct toolbar...also show your import that defined  on above your class name

Comment: Pls include the crash report

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android App Crashing at setSupportActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445564/android-app-crashing-at-setsupportactionbar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using the style **Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar**

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

And You are trying to set the data on to the default Action bar using these lines

```
setTitle("Coffee Hour");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Remove the above lines and try to run it. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Use this inside the **style.xml**

```
<style name="MyTheme.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Both of these are needed -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extended `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` theme. you don't need this line 
`<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>`