# Why I use 'androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar' to set toolbar，the app forced termination

Tags: java, android

when the app used **setSupportActionBar()** ,it can not to run.but can compile.

This my **active.java**

```
public class MainPay extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_pay);
        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);
        ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionbar != null){
            actionbar.hide();
        }
        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        mToolbar.setTitle("App Title");
//        mToolbar.setSubtitle("Sub Title");
//        mToolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
//        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
//        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

This is **toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:title="App Title"
        app:subtitle="Sub Title"
        app:navigationIcon="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my **Active.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".MainPay">

    <!--    <View-->
<!--        android:id="@+id/statusBarBackground"-->
<!--        android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
<!--        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />-->


    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I can compile it, but when open this active.the app forced termination

I delete this code in **active.java**

```
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

it's can run.
I want to add a back_button.
what's wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android App Crashing at setSupportActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445564/android-app-crashing-at-setsupportactionbar)

Comment: Post your full stacktrace